# main navigation jumps when you switch between to pages

Tags: javascript, html, menu, menuitem, listitem

I have a problem with the main menu on my website. When you select a project on the [portfolio site](http://short4u.de/54f4a7830664f) the main menu on top jumps a few pixels and the typography changes into bold. This phenomenon only happens when you switch between the portfolio and a project site. And it happens only on large displays.

I tried several things but I don't know what is causing this error. Even if I copy the html header code including the main menu from the portfolio site and paste it into a project site this strange thing is happening. Also an experimental version with "clearfix" did not load to the desired result. I know that there are some more errors but I first want to solve this problem.

I'm thankful for any support.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking, but I think you use a different font in your project site. 
If you look at the different letters, as the M, in one point the "v" part of the M hits te bottem, at the athor, it stops half way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I'm styling the navigation menu in my style.css. "Head" and "header" are the same for both sites – portfolio and projects. I really don't know why it looks different since on my MBP I cannot see any difference. The font is in both cases "Raleway 600". You can find the excerpt where the "navigationmain" is styled here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15159134/css_navigationmain.css